# webkit floats flicker on resize

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-float, flicker

I'm trying to create a 2d grid in HTML and CSS where resizing the window reflows elements to the appropriate row. The effect can be achieved by just floating fixed-width divs to the left, but I want to add a dynamic margin to minimize white space on the right of the screen.

My problem is when adding dynamic margins (b/t the divs) via javascript, the divs will appear to flicker (i.e. switch back an forth rapidly between rows) when resizing the browser window (only happens when width is **decreased**).

The bug manifests itself in webkit (chrome and safari), but not in Firefox. If it's just a webkit bug, is there a way to get around it?

An example can be seen on jsfiddle or a regular webpage:

http://jsfiddle.net/RAZHA/3/

http://alec.thewinograds.com/float_flicker_example.html

Thanks!

Comment: No. I couldn't get anything to work. I tried flooring the margins, decreasing them (so < 100% of the width was used). Dynamically changing a class rather than the styles...and some other things I don't remember atm.

Comment: This seems like a viable solution if anyone is still looking. http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/ 
http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/zimFC

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(box).css("margin-left", (marginSide * .5) - MARGIN_REDUCTION);
```

it seems to me to be a JS issue; reduce only margin margin not both.

http://jsfiddle.net/RAZHA/3/